# How can I make gfortran or ifort tell me when it implicitly promotes a REAL(4) to a REAL(8)?

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings, fortran90, gfortran

I am tasked with changing the precision of parts of an HPC application, bearing in mind that it makes heavy reliance on auto-vectorisation. It is therefore useful for the compiler to inform me when conversions of any type of floating point conversion occurs (as this could have a serious performance impact).

The  `-Wconversion` flag sounds like it should suit my needs:

> `-Wconversion`
>
> Warn about implicit conversions between different types.
>
> ---
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gfortran/Warning-Options.html

However, in practice, gfortran 5.2.0 only appears to report floating point demotions, *e.g.* `REAL(8)` to `REAL(4)`.

GCC has the `-Wdouble-promotion` flag - exactly what I need, but not available for gfortran. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

I am developing with gfortran, but ifort is available to me. However, I can't find any similar arguments for `-warn` (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525184).

How can I get either of these compilers to emit a warning when implicitly promoting a REAL?

Comment: You should probably read the documentation corresponding to the version of the compiler you use: the flags, and the stated meaning, change over time.

Comment: @francescalus Funnily enough, I did notice it was a different version, and I did find a more recent reference, which was the same. But, finding the Actually Up-To-Date page (which changed its name slightly), it is clear that the old `-Wconversion` has been split into `-Wconversion` and `-Wconversion-extra`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html

Comment: That said, I don't understand what's really going on with those flags: `-Wconversion-extra` doesn't (with 4.8.1) give me warnings for integer conversions.  I'd be interested to know whether it does with 5.2, or I'm just missing something.

Comment: @francescalus That's interesting - with 5.2, it reports `INTEGER(4)` to `INTEGER(8)`, `INTEGER` to `REAL`, and the reverse conversions. Presumably a bug in the early implementation.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to using gfortran 5.2.0, so let's look at the documentation for that version rather than 4.1.0.  This has [two relevant flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options) for what you consider:

```
-Wconversion  
    Warn about implicit conversions that are likely to change the
    value of the expression after conversion. Implied by -Wall.  
 -Wconversion-extra  
    Warn about implicit conversions between different types and
    kinds. This option does not imply -Wconversion.
```

If I use this latter flag with the following program

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real32, real64
  real(real64) x
  x = 1._real32
end
```

I get exactly (albeit using gfortran 4.8.1) a warning message requested in the question title

```
Warning: Conversion from REAL(4) to REAL(8) at (1)
```

whereas with just `-Wconversion` I get nothing.  If I change the program slightly, however, so that the changing of representable values kicks in, I get (different) warnings with each.

ifort, on the other hand (up to 19.0.5), appears to have no comparable warning.

Comment: Just my mistake, I confused that with -Winteger-division https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2015-07/msg00002.html

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I did see something in 6.0 about that flag warning about excess precision in a literal constant, was wondering whether that was it.