# Fortran compiler options to warn about assignment of single precision constant to a double precision variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Are there compilation options in gfortran and ifort that warn if I assign single precision number to a double precision variable? i.e. when I do this:

```
real(dp) :: number
number = 1.23 ! <---- I want to get compilation warning here
```

#### Example

```
program precision

 ! Double precision type
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(p = 15, r = 307)

real(dp) :: number

number = 1.3
print *, 'Garbage: ', number
! Prints 1.2999999523162842
! with nonsence digits after 7th decimal

number = 1.3_dp
print *, 'Legit: ', number
! Prints 1.3000000000000000
! with all digits we want

end program
```

I want to get a warning for `number = 1.3` assignment in above code. This is an easy mistake to make and messes up precision of my calculations.

#### Note

I'm aware of compilation options `-fdefault-double-8 -fdefault-real-8` for gfortran and `-r8` for ifort that magically make all single precision constants to be double precision. This is not what I want.

Comment: What effort have you put into reading the documentation that comes with your compilers?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it looks like a fair question to me. I'm not aware of any options myself.

Comment: There is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198305/is-there-a-gcc-flag-to-catch-integer-truncation but it warns for the other direction, assigning double to single.

Comment: For gfortran, you have [`-Wconversion-extra`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32054301/3157076).

Comment: @Ross, it was downvoted because it appears Evgenii made no attempt to read the document.  At with gfortran, its documentation includes an Option Index and a general Index.  Both contain entries for the relative options.

Comment: @francescalus thanks a lot! `-Wconversion-extra` option works (gfortran). Is there a similar option for ifort?

Comment: I'm not aware of a similar ifort option.